# PHP | Get private IP address from a client user?

Tags: php, http, curl, ip

I know question but didn't find real answer on stackoverflow. This is not `X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `SERVER_NAME` or `SERVER_REMOTE_ADDR`, I want get local IP address of remote client connected to my server to detect who is really on local remote network is connected.

Explain this:

```
ISP  <---->  ROUTER <----> LOCAL NETWORK <----> LOCAL PC
```

What I want to know?

1. Public IP address of connected remote client `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, okay, but!...
2. Local IP address of connected client on public network (192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, 172.x.x.x)

How to solve this problem? I have answer, so I think this should be know for everyone if want to know local IP address:

You should use `CURL` and `curl_getinfo()` function. Then, point URL address anyone that you want (your main server ip or whatever), for example:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $opt = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "YOUR_SOME_URL_ADDRESS"); 

    curl_exec($ch);

    $response = curl_getinfo($ch);

    $result = array('client_public_address' => $response["primary_ip"],
                    'client_local_address' => $response["local_ip"]
            );

    var_dump($result);

    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Focus on `$response["primary_ip"]` which responses your Public address and `$response["local_ip"]` which reponses local address. Now this is example:

```
ISP  <---->  ROUTER <----> LOCAL NETWORK <----> LOCAL PC
 /\                                              /\
 ||                                              ||
 \/                                              \/
$response["primary_ip"]                  <----> $response["local_ip"]
213.x.x.x  (for example)                        192.168.1.3 (for example)
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'client_public_address' => string '213.xxx.xxx.xxx' (length=14)
  'client_local_address'  => string '192.168.1.3' (length=11)
```

This will NOT be giving a REAL local IP address!

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the local IP address? There is the idea of session cookies in PHP and other means to uniquely identify a user.

Comment: **but this is how you get your server local IP** not client... enter your site using any proxy so you will see you are completely wrong

Comment: Think! You want locating a real person on the house who is connected? You didn't know if in house is too many people with different user_agent and ports? Your answer is grabbing their local IP address and ask to get which hostname is connected in the house?

Comment: It is always a good idea to test your inventions before posting them...

Comment: @MarinSagovac, even with a user agent and a private ip address, you cannot guarantee that this is the same person, more than one person could be using the particular computer with the same browser with the same windows/linux login, or no login at all, that is how almost all family computers work and how a lot of businesses work when using "hot desking".

Comment: `I think this could help many people` at this moment your are just confusing people, so let me clear it: **There is no way to get user/client private IP using HTTP** (in any language: PHP,Ruby,Java etc.)

Comment: This is not going to work. The user's private IP is none of our business

Comment: You can start by writing your own browser, that will add local IP in headers for every request.

Comment: Just try to imagine situation when hundreds or thousands of users share same IP address. Imagine dozens of routers between user's ISP and his computer. At the end, imagine this: multiple users are using SAME LOCAL IP on different routers, all connected to SAME SHARED PUBLIC IP. Not possible and useless.

Comment: (I'm putting this because this answer shows up HIGH ina google search on my question, to help others.) MY similar question is if both the server and the client are on a private network, with perhaps a NATing instance attached to an Internet gateway. The communication I want to get the client address for is the PRIVATE IP of the private client accessing the PRIVATE server. That SHOULD be the $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP' value, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never get to work.
First, you need an HTTP server on a client to make it response to CURL.
Even if ther would be - it is not guarantted to return whatever "local IP".
Next, an HTTP server which pings it's clients back looks suspicious and most likely gets banned.

Anyway, I tried your code on a remote IP:

```
array(2) {
  ["client_public_address"]=>
  string(7) "8.8.8.8"
  ["client_local_address"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

it returned nothing

While when I tried my local router it works okay

```
array(2) {
  ["client_public_address"]=>
  string(13) "XXX"
  ["client_local_address"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.1.37"
}
```

It works only for your **own local router**, but it cannot get whatever local address from a remote system.
Frankly, it shows you just local IP address assigned to your PC.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have been tested on VPS server it will return `NULL`. My mistakes, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The local IP addressed is not exposed to the application layer by default. You need lower level tools that can extract this information from the network packets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 features (CORS and WebSocket) for determining the range (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24) see this live example:

[JS-RECON](http://www.andlabs.org/tools/jsrecon.html)

How its work?
You can scan range of IP addresses (192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.0.1/24, etc) and find the range that used by user, however, finding exact IP address is still difficult.

Result:
Doesn't work. IP is 192.168.1.200 returns 192.168.1.2; site invalid, tools don't really work.

Comment: Tested. Not giving right results. It responses 192.168.x.x instead 10.1.x.x

Comment: did you clicked on 'Discover my private ip addresses?', any way, its only available tools.

Comment: Yes. I clicked on 'Discoer my private ip address' and scans ip address 192.168.0.x ...... and increases automatically.

Comment: yes, using HTML-Webworker you can scan list of IP in the background, once it found you can send it back using AJax...

Comment: I know why isn't works for me. I'm on linux, `Currently works on WINDOWS ONLY.`

Comment: no, the site uses predefined ip range, your router ip might not be listed there... the scanner depends on browser (if it supports HTML5 or not)

Answer (score -3):

```
    function getRealIpAddr(){ 
        //check ip from share internet 
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { 
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
         //to check ip is pass from proxy 
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else { 
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
        }

       return $ip; 
    }
```

Comment: This isn't for getting local IP address.