# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives the IP Address of the server instead of the IP Address of the user

Tags: php, ip-address

**EDIT:**

**I have cleaned the cache of my browser and now my PHP Code is working.**

---

I know that there are already similar questions and that i cannot trust in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`to get the real IP Address of a visitor.

I am testing my website on localhost and i am not behind any proxy, i am trying to display my IP Address but `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives `127.0.0.1` , namely the IP Address of the server.

**If i put the samecode online** in my server, **i receive again the IP Address of the server.**

I have tried without success with:

```
function get_visitor_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] . ' - ';
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']. ' - ';
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']. ' - ';
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']. ' - ';
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']. ' - ';
    }
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ipaddress .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. ' - ';
    }

    if($ipaddress == '') {
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

But again, it returns `127.0.0.1` .
Any alternative solution?

Comment: You might find an answer here [PHP | Get private IP address from a client user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044486/php-get-private-ip-address-from-a-client-user)

Comment: What IP adress are you expecting to get? On your local machine, connecting to your localhost.

Comment: @kerbholz my IP Address that i use to connect with internet, anyway if i put the same PHP Code online i receive always the IP Address of the server.

Comment: @Daniele You don't use the IP address you use to connect to the internet, because the connection never leaves your PC. You connect from your localhost to your localhost, so therefore you will see the IP of your localhost.

Comment: I'd assume you won't connect to your localhost via "internet". You're on the same machine, connecting "directly" to your localhost, so no "internet IP address" is involved.

Comment: @Ivar , kerbholz 
Ok! Please forget the example on localhost, i have the same problem if i put the same php code online in my server. I receive the IP Address of the server instead of the client.

Comment: Does you server happen to be operating behind a reverse proxy? At this stage I'd suggest `var_dump($_SERVER)` and check out what's there

Comment: @Phil i cannot answer at your question now, i am going to verify it. Anyway with `var_dump($_SERVER)` i have found my ip in:
 
`["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=>
  string(37) "MY IP, 127.0.0.1, THE IP OF THE SERVER"`

Comment: So why wasn't that showing up from your code `$ipaddress .= $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']. ' - ';`?

Comment: It is exactly the same thing that i have thinked.
I have tested the code several times and i have always received the IP Address of the server.

Comment: @Phil, now the PHP Code is working i have cleaned the cache of the browser....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means your server is probably behind some sort of reverse proxy, like a load balancer or CDN. Your PHP server is not receiving *direct* connections from clients, those connections go through some intermediate before, so the IP of that intermediate is all your server sees.

In this situation the intermediate proxy typically forwards the actual client's IP in some specified HTTP header to your PHP server. That is when you very explicitly and very selectively use something like `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']`; **if and only if and when you know that you're in this kind of situation and which HTTP header you can trust.** Consult the documentation of your host/proxy/network situation and it'll tell you what header to use.

Comment: As i have written to Phil `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']` finally gives to me the Client Ip Address.

Comment: Same thing happens when you use docker